# Modify Java sourcecode programmatically with Java or Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

To automate certain manual tasks in an legacy project, I need to modify existing java files from within java or groovy code.

I don´t want to use RegEx, because it would be neither quick nor clean in my opinion.

I found javassist and srcgen4javassist. The first one lets me modify my sources as I wish, but only writes bytecode, loosing all comments and annotations. And with the second one I didnt manage to read an existing Class not created with srcgen4javassist itself.

Is there an elegant solution, or do i need to bite the bullet and use Regex?

Comment: What is it that you want to do? An example would help.

Comment: I need to edit a sourcefile automatically, in a way the new created lines look the same as the original manual written ones. I´d like to add a new field to the group of similar fields. I´d like to add a new getter to return that fields value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could really parse the code using something like eclipse's [ASTParser](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTParser.html) at which point you coudl locate your replacement targets xpath-style, but its a lot of work.

you could also consider marking replacement areas with annotation and [writing an annotation processor to generate/alter sources at runtime](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/), but (at least in my opinion) the API is cumbersome.

you can combine regexp with some marker in the source code, something like

```
//START REPLACEMENT-TARGET 
...code to be edited/replaced
//END REPLACEMENT TARGET
```

which would make your regexp targeting a lot safer.

Comment: Thanks radai, I took the regexp path. Its the most straightforward way right now.